# Javascript: Animation Question

Tags: javascript, animation

This problem should be simple enough, i am trying to learn animation using javascript and to begin i have an image of a ball that i want to move to the left a single px at a time. here's what i have so far:

**style.css**

```
 #field {

   height:200px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }
```

**animation.js**

```
 function move()
 {
        ball = document.getElementById('ball');

    ball.style.right = (ball.style.right + 1) + "px";
 }
```

**index.html**

```
 <link href="../js2/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="animattion.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>


     <div id="field">
             <img src="ball.gif" id="ball" />
     </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
             setInterval(move,20);
    </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

this is what i have so far and the ball doesn't seem to move. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: for loops are not appropriate for animation. See the answers below for details on setTimeout/setInterval.

Comment: I have made the setInterval changes however the ball still isn't moving. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just wrap the animation in a for-loop. You will see nothing and it will be too fast. You need to wrap around using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.  Something like this

```
setInterval(move, 20 /*milliseconds, 50frames/second */)
```

You also need to strip 'px' from style.right and parse int. I think you can do

```
parseInt(obj.style.right.replace('px', ''))
```

Here is a demo! http://jsfiddle.net/t6PY5/

Comment: I replaced the for loop with setInterval(move,20); and the ball still doesn't move

Comment: tried your second comment as well and it still doesn't work i added the following to my animation.js

function move()
{
 ball = document.getElementById('ball');
  ball.style.right = (ball.style.right + 10) + 'px';
 parseInt(ball.style.right.replace('px', ''));
 
}

Comment: You need to init to 1px first.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setInterval(func|code, delay)` instead of loop.

```
<div id="text">test</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById('test');
var left = 0;
setInterval(function(){
   div.style.left = left++ + 'px';
}, 100);
</script>
```